# Problem with POST method in RESTful Java Web Service

Tags: java, rest, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to make a RESTful Web Service which implements all four CRUD operations. I got stuck in "Create" because somehow I'm not able to obtain the posted data. Here is the method I wrote. Just as a info, I'm using Jersey RI of JAX-RS + JAXB XML to serialize objects.

Here it is:

```
@POST
@Consumes("application/xml")
public Response createStudent(InputStream is) {
 Student st = this.readStudent(is);
 st.setUserId(idCounter.incrementAndGet());
 studentDB.put(st.getUserId(), st);
 System.out.println("Created student " + st.getUserId());
 return Response.created(URI.create("/student/"+ st.getUserId())).build();

}
```

And the readStudent method is below:

```
 protected Student readStudent(InputStream is){

 JAXBContext ctx;

 Student st = null;
 try { 
  String xml = is.toString();
     System.out.println(xml);
  ctx = JAXBContext.newInstance(Student.class);
   st = (Student) ctx.createUnmarshaller().unmarshal(new StringReader(xml));
   return st;
 } catch (JAXBException e){
  e.printStackTrace();
 } 
 finally { return st; }

}
```

Can someone give me some light about this? I exhausted every idea to make this works and nothing worked!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After sweating hard looking for a answer, I've managed to fix it! It was just a missing dependency to resteasy-jaxb-provider.jar . Without this .jar the servlet wasn't able to do the automatic conversion from POJO to XML and vice-versa

Answer (score 2):

I think your problem is the line in which you use the `toString()` method to get the string of the `InputStream`:

```
String xml = is.toString();
```

You should read the data in the input stream and append it to a new string. The `toString()` is a string representation of the stream, but not the contents of it. You have to use the `read` methods of the `InputStream` and append the bytes to a new `String` using a `StringBuilder` or a `StringWriter`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you don't have `createStudent(Student student)` instead. The whole idea of jsr311 is for the parameters to also be parsed and given to the function.

**EDIT**
For a second I thought I was confusing things. But I found an example here http://blogs.oracle.com/enterprisetechtips/entry/configuring_json_for_restful_web

```
@PUT
       @Consumes("application/json")
       public synchronized void setStatus(StatusInfoBean status) {
          ...
       }
```

So you don't even need to parse xml or json. This work is already done for you

Comment: Hm, tried that and received this message while trying to curl the URI:
  Could not find message body reader for type: class com.esconn.domain.Student of content type: application/xml